# Что такое "прототипы" и как их использовать?

Tags: perl

Собственно, что такое прототипы в Perl? Зачем они и где могут быть нужны? И как правильно их использовать?

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что это тоже не вопрос, а попытка перенести сюда пару страниц из общедоступных учебников?

Comment: @PinkTux "Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь публиковать свои заметки или переводы в виде «вопроса с ответом», которые могут появляться у вас в процессе изучения новых технологий. Уверен, сообщество будет благодарно вам за это!"

Comment: @PinkTux взято отсюда http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2983/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3-%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2. Как думаете админ прав по поводу благодарности?

Comment: Я вот не считаю что тут это полезно, тем более так сформулированное. Что бы этот вопрос нашелся человек уже должен знать слово "прототип". А когда человек знает это слово гугл ему тут же выдает соответствующие главы учебников, где это разжевано. На SO лично я за такой информацией и не подумал идти

Comment: "Как думаете админ прав по поводу благодарности?" - мне всё равно. Просто уточнил, действительно этот вопрос задан честно интересующимся человеком (тогда ответил бы что-нибудь), или нет (тогда и пальцы напрягать не буду).

Comment: @Mike по этой тематике толково разжеванная информация есть, да, но на английском, просто вбейте в Google запрос "прототипы в perl" и "prototypes in perl" для сравнения. P.S. Куча толковой информации по ним кстати на enSO.

Comment: @PinkTux уточняю,  да это действительно мне интересно, и на данный момент всеобъемлющего ответа на него у меня нет. Поэтому жду ответов от других участников, а в случае их отсутствия буду искать информацию для написания своего собственного.

Comment: Может вы тогда зададите более конкретный вопрос, на основании того, что именно вам не понятно в прототипах. Ибо описания которые я вижу в интернете занимают страницы 2. И вы считаете, что в них материал раскрыт не полностью. Это значит что вы видимо ожидаете ответ страницы на 4. А 4 страницы это не формат SO.

Comment: Вот например у Лари Уолла описание прототипов занимает 7 страниц и мне лично кажется, что там изложены все тонкости. Но переписывать сюда 7 страниц текста ... это как то черезчур.

Comment: ftp://ftp.micronet-rostov.ru/linux-support/books/programming/Perl/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%A3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB,%20%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%B8%20%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%20-%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20Perl,%203-%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20-%202002.pdf  см. страницу 271

Comment: 1. [Введение в Perl. Подпрограммы](http://citforum.ru/internet/perl_tut/sub.shtml)
 2. [Сигнатуры функций в Perl 5.20](http://pragmaticperl.com/issues/13/pragmaticperl-13-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-perl-5.20.html)
3. [Функции в
    Perl](https://habrahabr.ru/company/regru/blog/232933)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Что такое прототипы?

**Прототип** - это образец аргументов функции, который используется компилятором для проверки правильности переданных параметров, а также для изменения их контекста для данной функции.

#### Как их можно использовать?

Использовать их можно сразу после имени функции в скобках, например: `sub foo($$$) { ... }`.
А если же в программе включена поддержка сигнатур `use feature 'signatures'`, то прототипы необходимо будет задавать в атрибуте `:prototype()`, так как скобки после имени функции будут отданы сигнатурам.

Сами же прототипы определяются с помощью комбинации из нескольких символов: `$ ; @ + * & \[]`. Подробнее о них можно прочитать [здесь](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes).

#### Зачем они и где могут быть нужны?

Основное предназначение прототипов заключается в том, чтобы позволить пользовательским функциям вести себя
как встроенные в Perl. Например:

```
sub foo { ... }
foo(@some_array); # в @_ - будет содержаться весь массив, т.е
                  # $_[0] = $some_array[0];
                  # $_[1] = $some_array[1];
                  # и т.д.
```

а эта же функция с прототипом, позволит изменить данное поведение:

```
sub foo (+) { ... }
foo(@some_array); # теперь в @_ будет содержаться только один элемент
                  # который является ссылкой на массив @some_array.
```

Т.е. это как если бы данную функцию (без прототипа), вызвали так: `foo(\@some_array)`.

Из интересных же особенностей можно также упомянуть про возможность создания нового синтаксиса, когда в функцию можно передать анонимную функцию, без указания ключевого слова sub.

```
sub do_something_in_block (&) {
    print $_[0]->();
}

do_something_in_block { my $a = 8; $a *= $a; };
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот вполне понятная статья про прототипы: https://habrahabr.ru/company/regru/blog/232933/ , да и не только про них.

Comment: Ну, это же ответ-ссылка! Ответы-ссылки у нас тут не приветствуются. Если вы хотите рассказать что-то по теме, напишите краткую выжимку смысла статьи в ответе.

Comment: А как ещё можно отвечать на вопросы уровня "прочитайте мне ман"? По мне так удалять такие вопросы надо, без голосования, если в них не содержится "ман прочитал и вот что не понял...".